# What's the right way to shutdown a SQL Server 2008 R2 cluster?

Tags: sql-server, cluster, failovercluster

I'm new to SQL Server 2008 R2 cluster. I just created a test environment now I need to shut it down. I know SQL Server cluster is a high availability solution so there is seldom mentioned that how to do this. Are there anything special to shut down a SQL Server cluster?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it through cluster administrator. The reason for this is that if you just shut down the service on a given node, the cluster will detect that and bring it up on another node in the cluster. You'll typically want to control if/when that happens, which is why you do it through cluster admin.